Перезапуск бота при входе
Всем привет!
Python. Telebot.
Можно ли как-то принудительно запускать определённую функцию при входе, когда пользователь долго не заходил в бот? Поясню. Пользователь зашёл в бот, добрался до нужной информации и вышел. В крайнем сообщении от бота была клавиатура. Инфа для некоторых следующих шагов хранится в оперативке в словаре по id юзера. Я, допустим, провожу работы и перезапускаю поллинг. Пользователь через какое-то время заходит в бот и перед ним клавиатура, на которой он остановился. Он что-то жмёт, и бот падает, потому что не знает что делать, так как оперативка очищена. Чтобы этого не произошло, логично, чтобы пользователь перезапустил бот, а именно в данном случае нажал /start, и была бы вызвана начальная функция, с которой всё начнёт работать корректно. Если это поможет, то в словаре у меня хранятся предыдущие колбеки.
